# php imagick: tif/tiff always 160x160 pixels

Tags: php, image, imagick, image-size

I'm using the imagick-extension for php to convert images. Everything works fine, except the conversion of tif/tiff images. When I use the code below (I simplified the code for testing purposes):

```
<?php
    $image = new imagick("myImage.tif");
    var_dump($image->getImageGeometry());
?>
```

I always get the following for images which are larger than 160x160 px:

> array(2) { ["width"]=> int(160) ["height"]=> int(160) }

For instance... the image is originally 1000x1000 px... but Imagick means the image is only 160x160. I also tried the getimagesize()-function of php which also says 1000x1000 px (and not 160x160). But when I use images which are smaller than 160x160 I get the correct size...

I already spent some hours to figure out what's the problem without any solution. Is there any limitation in Imagick for tif/tiff-images or does anyone know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: What version of Imagick are you using.  I am unable to replicate your issue.  My version as per:  `$imagick = new Imagick(); $imagick->getVersion()`
`array(
  "versionNumber" => 1620,
  "versionString" => "ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org",
)`

Comment: I'm using 6.7.9 (array(2) { ["versionNumber"]=> int(1657) ["versionString"]=> string(61) "ImageMagick 6.7.9-8 2012-09-27 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org" })

Comment: Are you still having the issue?  I would doublecheck (you never know) the images with an image editor such as Photoshop, and maybe spin up a VM running CentOS with a clean install of Imagemagick and see if it is still happening.  If not, then it must be something in the configuration of your system that is causing the odd behavior.

Comment: Yes... I'm still having the issue. I created the tif/tiff-files using PaintShop X4 (Corel) and all other applications (Paint.net) and Windows Explorer says 1000x1000 pixels. But I'll double check it during the next time...